# Issue with httpclient.PutAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am facing an issue while making changes to the database using httpclient.putasync. following is the error message i receive : **error while copying content to a stream**
Any help would be great

```
namespace ABC
{
    public enum SupportedHttpMethods
    {
        GET,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE
    }

public class HttpClass : IHttpClass
{
    Uri _uri;
    HttpMethod _httpMethod;
    StringContent _content;
    HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true, AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip});
    Action _action;
    HttpResponseMessage _httpResponseMessage;

    public HttpClass(
      SupportedHttpMethods httpMethod,
      string uri,
      string content)
        : this(httpMethod, uri)
    {

        if (httpMethod == SupportedHttpMethods.POST || httpMethod == SupportedHttpMethods.PUT)
        {
            JObject.Parse(content);
            _content = new StringContent(content);
            _content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidHttpMethodContentCombinationException();
        }
    }

    public HttpClass(
      SupportedHttpMethods httpMethod,
      string uri)
    {
        _uri = new Uri(uri);
        _httpMethod = new HttpMethod(httpMethod.ToString());
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")
            );

        switch (httpMethod)
        {

            case SupportedHttpMethods.GET:
                _action = get;
                break;

            case SupportedHttpMethods.POST:
                _action = post;
                break;

            case SupportedHttpMethods.PUT:
                _action = put;
                break;

            case SupportedHttpMethods.DELETE:
                _action = delete;
                break;

            default:
                throw new InvalidHttpMethodException();
        }
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage GetHttpResponseMessage()
    {

        return _httpResponseMessage;
    }


    public string GetResponseContent()
    {

        if (_httpMethod.Method == SupportedHttpMethods.GET.ToString())
            return _httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return null;

    }

    public void Invoke()
    {
        _action.Invoke();
    }


    void delete()
    {
        _httpResponseMessage = _httpClient.DeleteAsync(_uri).Result;
    }
    void get()
    {
        _httpResponseMessage = _httpClient.GetAsync(_uri).Result;
    }
    void post()
    {
        _httpResponseMessage = _httpClient.PostAsync(_uri, _content).Result;
    }
    void put()
    {
        _httpResponseMessage = _httpClient.PutAsync(_uri, _content).Result;

    }
}

public class InvalidHttpMethodContentCombinationException : Exception
{
    public InvalidHttpMethodContentCombinationException()
        : base("When speciying content, either a POST or PUT must be used") { }
}

public class InvalidHttpMethodException : Exception
{
    public InvalidHttpMethodException()
        : base("Only PUT, POST, GET and DELETE Methods are supported") { }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: error while copying content to a stream. this is the inner exception i see

Comment: Ideally, you need to provide _both_ a complete, concise code example that reliably reproduces the problem _and_ complete error information, including the full stack trace(s) for any exception(s) and their messages. At a _minimum_, you must provide at least one or the other. Last I checked, there still weren't any psychics answering questions here.